# Xcode error - use of undeclared identifier 'GAdInterstitialKey_Live'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I'm trying to build this project in Xcode8 I get this error

> use of undeclared identifier 'GAdInterstitialKey_Live'

on this line

```
    interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:GAdInterstitialKey_Live];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have that string in some part of your code? By the way, are you using admob? Interstitial might be related to it.

Assuming you are using something like admob you have to define keys provided by the service to relate the user to your app. You might not have defined then or dit it in a wrong way.

Comment: Do you have your admob keys? I have never implemented admob on Ios, but as far as i know you will have to create a variable and put your key into it. interstitial needs to receive your interstitial key(full screen ads)

Comment: On the other hand if you are not planning on use interstitial ads you could simply comment this line. But make sure your other keys like banners are defined, or you will fall into the same error.

Comment: thanks, I removed the line it builds correctly now. but there's one more problem the interstitial ad is appearing after xx clicks how to find the code who's controlling the time?

Comment: Im really no sure about this second problem. Try to search your code for words like ad, admob, interstitial and NSTimeInterval. The best way would probably open a new question and provide some code. Also if the question helped you consider upvoting it and choosing a correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: it require to have 15rep to vote for you but i'll chose you answer don't worry